# Filter and calculate array values in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a quiz/test app. I have 4 values as strings (from the previous activities, selected by the user via radio buttons) passed onto the last "result" activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auswertung);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String strSommerWinter = intent.getStringExtra("strSommerWinter");
    final String strUrlaubsart = intent.getStringExtra("strUrlaubsart");
    final String strRegion = intent.getStringExtra("strRegion");
    final String strAnreise = intent.getStringExtra("strAnreise");

}
```

They're all numbers (could/should probably change them to int I guess), for example 1, 1, 6, 10.
Then I have this array:

```
int [][] destiBewertung = {{3,4,2,0,1,3,5,0,0,2,3,3,5,4},
                            {1,3,5,4,4,4,3,3,2,5,0,0,5,4},
                            {3,3,1,4,5,4,2,5,4,3,0,0,5,4},
                            {1,3,4,4,4,3,4,3,0,5,5,3,4,4},
                            {1,3,3,4,4,5,2,4,4,5,0,0,5,4},
                            {3,4,3,1,1,3,5,0,1,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,5,5,2,2,3,5,0,0,1,5,5,5,3},
                            {3,5,5,0,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,2,1,3,4,4,1,5,0,2,5,4,0,1},
                            {3,1,5,3,1,3,2,2,0,5,3,0,5,0},
                            {3,4,3,3,3,2,5,0,2,5,5,5,5,3},
                            {3,5,3,3,5,3,2,4,5,5,0,0,5,4},
                            {3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,3,5,0,0,5,3},
                            {3,3,2,4,4,3,3,5,1,5,5,5,5,3},
                            {3,5,3,0,2,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,5,3,2,2,3,5,1,3,4,3,0,5,3},
                            {3,4,5,1,2,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,3},
                            {3,4,2,2,3,3,5,2,3,1,3,3,5,1},
                            {3,4,3,4,3,2,5,2,2,5,4,3,5,3},
                            {3,4,5,1,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,3,2,4,5,4,2,4,4,5,5,0,2,0},
                            {1,3,0,4,5,5,0,5,4,3,3,4,0,5},
                            {3,2,3,4,5,4,2,4,2,5,3,3,4,3},
                            {3,4,3,2,1,3,5,0,2,4,5,3,5,3},
                            {3,4,3,3,2,3,5,0,0,5,5,5,5,5},
                            {3,5,3,1,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,5,3,1,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,4},
                            {3,4,0,5,5,5,1,5,4,0,3,0,4,0},
                            {3,4,4,1,2,3,5,2,1,3,0,0,5,4},
                            {3,5,3,2,1,3,5,0,1,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,4,3,1,1,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,5,4,0,0,2,5,1,0,1,1,4,4,4},
                            {1,5,3,1,1,3,5,0,2,4,3,3,5,3},
                            {3,4,4,1,0,3,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {1,2,1,4,5,5,1,5,3,5,5,5,5,4},
                            {3,3,3,2,1,3,5,1,0,0,5,5,5,1},
                            {2,1,1,3,5,5,1,5,5,0,5,5,5,0},
                            {3,1,1,4,5,4,0,5,5,0,5,5,3,0},
                            {1,1,0,5,5,4,0,5,0,5,3,3,0,5},
                            {1,3,3,4,5,5,3,5,3,5,2,0,4,4}
};
```

The first column (position 0?) is either 1, 2 or 3. If the first string (strSommerWinter) is 1, only the rows where the first value is 1 should be considered further.
The last 3 strings (strUrlaubsart, strRegion, strAnreise) are columns of the array that should be summed up. This picture should make it clearer what I'm trying to do:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDWaU.jpg)

I guess I need ArrayList and a new array for the results.. but I have no idea how to start. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function below:

```
private List<Integer> getSelectedRowSums(
        int sommerWinter,
        int urlaubsart,
        int region,
        int anreise,
        int[][] destiBewertung
) {
    List<Integer> selectedRowSumList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] columns : destiBewertung) {
        if (columns[0] == sommerWinter) {
            int sum = columns[urlaubsart] + columns[region] + columns[anreise];
            selectedRowSumList.add(sum);
        }
    }
    return selectedRowSumList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!